How to read and set app title and favicon from appConfig in Vue
I have a requirement to read the app title and favicon from appConfig because I have multiple environments with different appconfigs. It can't be done directly in index.html because appConfig can not be imported at this point. The other option is to do it in main.ts since it is the first thing loaded and if I do it there, first on page load a default title from index.html is displayed, and then replace with one from config. I am new to Vue and need help on how to avoid this behavior.
